# Android create custom IM type

Tags: android

In my android application I want to create a custom type of IM that should be editable via standard contacts editing application. There are several built-it IMs that user can select from: Aim, Windows Live, Yahoo, etc. I want to add "My Very Best IM" to the list, so that user can pick it quickly without the need to enter the "custom" text and value by hand. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add this functionality to the inbuilt contacts app.

In other words, you cannot tell that this app should show up in that list.

Comment: Well, maybe not directly but by adding custom data field for every created contact (to the Data tables), or it is absolutely impossible to make default contacts app display custom data?

Comment: It's absolutely impossible to make the default contacts app to display custom data, even if you create custom mimetypes.

Comment: Great, at least "this is impossible" is also a good answer to the question. I was hoping to find some kind of "workaround" for it. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Write your own contacts application, that the only workaround for this.